# Visual Basic 6 - Runtime Error 75 - Path/File Access Error

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

We have an enterprise **VB6** application, this application require access to many shared resources. For testing purposes of new added functionality we have released a new version, then we set permissions to the users that will be testing the new functionality. In short we have *prepare the scenario for the application test/validation to succeed*.

When trying to run the application in some user's PC using some development user account we succeed, but when we try to access to the same executable with the user account we receive a runtime **Error 75 - Path/File Access Error**.

Some ideas about the origin of such error? all the ideas will be appreciate.

*Note*: It is important to say that developers and users both are in the same intra-net and also in the same network domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to debug it, you could watch it with a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645) and just see the last accessed file system object. It most likely tries to access or do something the user account doesn't have or where there are insufficient rights. Its almost impossible to get the exact reason just from the error message (as the error number is more generic and will popup for different ressources or file operations).

Comment: I will consider the usage of Proccess Monitor or some tool like that. For now we have solved our problem, probably some developer was trying to overwrite the file while the test took place.

Answer (score 2):

The error almost always indicates a simple security violation.  Could be file permissions, or as simple as trying to write to a file marked read-only.

Or the path can be invalid for the user, such as trying to open a file on a drive letter that doesn't exist for the user.

Simply looking up error 75 in the VB6 manual will list most of the possibilities.